# Didn't have + past participle

Tags: sentence-construction

Can we use past. Participle after didn't have ?

This is because we use first form of verb after did.

For example,

> I'm so sorry John I didn't have asked that question.

Answer (score 1):

No. The negation of the present perfect is formed as

> (subject)  have not (past participle)

The word "not" is usually reduced to "n't" Eg. "I haven't asked that question" or "He hasn't eaten dinner".

You cannot form "do have asked". If emphasis is required, it is done by the intonation.

The present perfect can be used with modals, like "should":

> I shouldn't have asked that question.